# Multiple Instance of Enum found in Java Heap Dump

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC web application deployed in Tomcat.  I am doing load testing of Web application and created a heap dump using the VisualVM profiling tool and analyzed it with that.

I found that there is more than one instance of Enum found in the dump. But as per my knowledge, Enum is static and one per JVM.

MyEnum is

```
Enum DayOfWeek{
           SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT
}
```

From the concept, its instances should be 7 but I got 21 instance in dump.

What is the reason behind the multiple instances of Enum? I have not created any loader to load Enum.

Comment: Every member of an enum is an instance. For example, Month.JANUARY and Month.FEBRUARY are 2 instances of Month. So it's not surprising to find several instances of the same enum.

Comment: An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. Enums are not static, they are constants. [see this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)